# extending a directive in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I know this question has been asked many times however I followed the process and something isn't working for some reason.

Could someone kindly point out if I'm forgetting something obvious please, here is the boiled down example:
https://embed.plnkr.co/NzynFyfNM0HgQyt6X4Hc/

I extended the `mat-sort-header` directive from [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview) and only changed the `selector`. I then applied the resulting `custom-mat-sort-header` directive to the Weight column.

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: @Edric no error, it just doesn't do anything. You can see in the plunkr